# Printf is not working in AJAX php file?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, printf

Hi I want to update some data in my mysql database by using form in html and AJAX  technology. I have problem because data is not updated after click on submit and in response message I have not only message but clear mysql ask too! Let's look at my alert:
[image]

My idea is the printf is not really post text into "query" function but this text output is going stright into response data and query is always wrong from empty text...

Let's look at my AJAX php file:

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 error_reporting(0);
 $imie = $_POST['imie'];
 $nazwisko = $_POST['nazwisko'];
 $kodpocztowy = $_POST['kodpocztowy'];
 $ulica = $_POST['ulica'];
 $nrdomu = $_POST['nrdomu'];
 $nrmieszkania = $_POST['nrmieszkania'];
 $miasto = $_POST['miasto'];

 try
 {
  if (! @include_once('connect.php'))
    throw new Exception ('connect.php kurwa nie istnieje</br>');
  if (!file_exists('connect.php' ))
    throw new Exception ('connect.php nie istnieje</br>');
  else
    require_once('connect.php'); 
 }
 catch(Exception $e)
 {    
    echo "Wiadomość: " . $e->getMessage();
    echo "Kod: " . $e->getCode();
 }
 require_once "connect.php";

 $polaczenie = @new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
 if($rezultat = @$polaczenie->query(printf("UPDATE adresy SET imie='%s', nazwisko='%s', kodpocztowy='%s', ulica='%s', nrdomu='%s', nrmieszkania='%s', miasto='%s' WHERE id=%s",$imie,$nazwisko,$kodpocztowy,$ulica,$nrdomu,$nrmieszkania,$miasto,$_SESSION['id'])))
 {
  $polaczenie->close();
  echo "Good!";
 }
 else
 {
  $polaczenie->close();
  echo "Not good!";
 }

 
?>
```

Have you any idea how to solve this problem? Maybe what to use instead printf or echo? Please help, greatings.

Answer (score 5):

printf() prints out the text directly, you do actually want to use [sprintf()](http://php.net/sprintf), which returns the string instead of printing it out.

Some side notes though:

1. Using "@" before function calls is almost never good practice, you should probably remove them
2. You should probably also dig deeper into something called "[SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)"

Comment: " you do actually want to use sprintf(), which returns the string instead of printing it out." Yes but how?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your asking: In the line that starts with `if($rezultat = @$polaczenie->query`, just replace the `printf` with `sprintf` (or rather, just add an `s` at the start).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is indeed `printf`.

You should use `sprintf` which *returns* a string instead of `printf` which *displays* the string

From the docs:

[sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>   sprintf — Return a formatted string

[printf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)

> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>   printf — Output a formatted string